# ffi_lib and scrypt dependency errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have been getting this error while trying to start my rails server:

> /Users/Findeii/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@pricebook/gems/ffi-1.9.6/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in
>   `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library
>   '/Users/Findeii/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@pricebook/gems/scrypt-2.0.0/ext/scrypt/x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext.bundle':
>   dlopen(/Users/Findeii/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@pricebook/gems/scrypt-2.0.0/ext/scrypt/x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext.bundle,
>   5): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)

1. I have found that that scrypt is needing i386 and ruby is running in x86_64, but I don't know how to solve that dependency issue. (Mac OSX Yosemite, hackintosh)
2. I don't know how to solve the block in the ffi_lib (or if it will be solved with resolving the dependency issue.)

I have tried uninstalling the scrypt and ffi gems and re-installing - problem still there.
I have tried uninstalling all gems, gemsets, and ruby versions - problem still there.

I am using Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 1.9.3 (I know its old but I am just doing part time for a company that is still using it)

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/issues/36

Comment: I already saw that and tried the solutions, none seemed to be able to resolve the problems

Comment: Worth trying a newer version of ruby 1.9.3. p0 is super old

Comment: Yeah, but that wont fix the issue with scrypt being a i386 and my system being x86_64. I am working to get the company to move it to a new ruby version, but that doesn't help me in the meantime.